# get file response progress from server

Tags: node.js

Got a server that sends huge files ~50MB as response.

Using http and piping the file as follows:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fileSystem = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    // We replaced all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
    readStream.pipe(response);
})
.listen(2000);
```

As expected, it takes a huge amount of time to send the response. But I want to have a responsive page when the request is being made.

Anyway I can send the progress of the response that is sent have it show at the frontend?
Can use I socket.io?

What I have tried so far:

1. Tried calling the `pipe` event on the `readStream` but it was called only once.

```
.on("pipe", (src) => {
      console.log("Something is piping into the writer.");
      // assert.equal(src, reader);
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried listening on the [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) ?

Comment: This should be done in the client part, not on the server side. Wait on the client request to receive the header (file size) and measure the received bytes.